# Delete rows from Kendo Grid with Pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, kendo-grid, datasource

I have a kendo grid(with pagination Enabled) with some entries. Say, I have 5 pages and I have selected(clicked on checkbox) one row from each page and then clicked on top level action DELETE. I am not able to figure out how to delete the entries from the grid and the data source?

**I tried below code, which deletes the entries from the page which is visible in the grid (on screen)**

```
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        var userSelectionInfo = usersService.getUserSelectionInfo();
        for(var userName in userSelectionInfo) {
            if(userSelectionInfo[userName]) {
                var selector = '#' + userName+ '_actions';
                grid.removeRow($(selector).closest('tr'));
            }
        }
```

**I tried one more approach:**

I created an array of objects which will remain after deletion operation from the original array of objects and then added into the grid data source.

```
    var newData = [];
    var userSelectionInfo = usersService.getUserSelectionInfo();
    for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        if(users[i].userName&& !userSelectionInfo[users[i].userName]) {
            newData.push(users[i]);
        }
    }
    loadUsersIntoGrid(newData);
```

Is there any better approach or kendo API which I am missing?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete from the dataSource instead of grid.First push the id of each selected item to an array, say DeleteList. Then you can delete from the datasource on clicking the top DELETE.

```
for(i=0; i<= DeleteList.length; i++)
{
  grid.dataSource.remove(grid.dataSource.get(DeleteList[i]));
}
```

Comment: grid.dataSource.get(DeleteList[i]) is giving undefined

Comment: DeleteList will be a array for storing Ids that needs to be deleted. First you will have to define the array and push Ids into it.